Scheduled task Failing - Redshift
I have a scheduled task that calls a stored procedure in a Redshift database. If I execute it manually, it works fine, only the scheduled is failing, but I'm not able to see WHY the query is failing. Where can I find the logs/Error message?
I tried querying stl_error table but I got this error: "ERROR: permission denied for relation stl_error"

They’ve added a section to their docs showing how to assume the role that’s executing the query and see the error of the last query guid that got executed. Usually it’s cause the iam user they add (select * from pg_users) doesn’t have permissions to run be query, I usually just grant them sys:superuser role.
